# Views with variable contentBindings

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to use templates for a `selectionBinding` value? Here is what I'm trying to do:

Controller:

```
App.testController = Em.Object.create({
    content:[
       {title: "abc", index: 1, model: App.s1 },
       {title: "def", index: 2, model: App.s2 }
     ]
}}
```

View:

```
{{#each App.testController.content}}
  Title: {{title}} Model: {{model}} Index: {{index}}
  {{view Ember.Select
       // doesn't work
       selectionBinding="App.s" + {{index}}" + ".selected"
       contentBinding="App.s" + {{index}} + ".content"
  }}
}}
```

In other words, each view inside the iteration needs to be tied to its own model, so any variation of the above syntax would be welcome. I tried using the `[]` syntax and also `.get({{index})` without any success.

What exactly am I allowed to use after a `selectionBinding=`?

Comment: How about a computed property which generates the string to bind ?

Answer (score 0):

Only a string property path may be used for a binding string.

In your example, it would be better bind to `model.selected` and `model.content`.